# Introduction of env --null

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, env

I have tried to [extract environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22086176/2838364) in a Python process with help of `env --null`, which works even for environment variables containing newline character.

But on some machines I have received an error:

```
> env -0
env: invalid option -- '0'

> env --null
env: unrecognized option '--null'

> env --version
env (GNU coreutils) 6.12
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

In which version was the argument introduced? Is there any alternative command to extract the environment?

Comment: On Linux: `cat /proc/self/environ`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option `-0/--null` was first introduce on 28-10-2009, and release with GNU coreutils version 8.1.

If your coreutils is too old, you should upgrade. Or you can use `perl`:

```
perl -e '$ENV{_}="/usr/bin/env"; print "$_ => $ENV{$_}\0" for keys %ENV'
```

As @Stéphane Chazelas pointed out in his comment, the above approach doesn't include environment strings that don't contain `=`, duplicated environment variables or environment variables with null name.

If you are in Linux, you can use (Thanks @Stéphane Chazelas again):

```
cat /proc/self/environ
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't include the environment strings that don't contain `=` or duplicated env vars or env vars with the null name (`=value` env strings).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Can you give example for each of them? I even don't know how can we create env vars with null name.

Comment: `tcc -run - <<< 'int main() { char*e[] = { "a=b", "a=c", "", "=", 0}; execle("/usr/bin/env", "env", "-0", 0, e); }'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for that information, updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with python anyway you could use:

```
import os
import sys

for k in sorted(os.environ):
    if k == '_':
        v = '/usr/bin/env'
    else:
        v = os.environ[k]
    sys.stdout.write("{}={}\0".format(k, v))
```

to get very similar output compared to `env --null`.